# replacing a variable in a list using a for-loop?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I am trying to replace the value 11 with the value of 1.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

I want it to be:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]
```

Comment: "i" is not the index, you should use an index

Comment: Please add your code as text, not as an image.

Comment: could you show an answer?

Comment: `for i in range(len(cards)): if cards[i]==11: cards[i]=1`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please do not upload images of code when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Instead, copy and paste it with [proper formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(len(cards)):
    if cards[i]==11:
        cards[i]=1
```

Comment: this is unidiomatic. You should use `enumerate` here.

Answer (score 0):

In your exampe `i` is an item in list, not an index:

```py
cards = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]

for i, val in enumerate(cards):
    if val == 11:
        cards[i] = 1


print(cards)
```

Comment: this is unidiomatic, you should use `enumerate` here

Comment: Why? You don't need a value in that example to use `enumerate`

Comment: You do, you are using `cards[i]`

Comment: Man, there is no such a word as `unidiomatic` )) - https://dictionary.cambridge.org/spellcheck/english/?q=unidiomatic

Comment: You should use: `not idiomatic`

Comment: No, you should not use not idiomatic code ...

Comment: @var211 https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/unidiomatic shh

Comment: Just kidding, I agree and changed my code. You right.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a list comprehension:

```
cards = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]
[1 if i==11 else i for i in cards]
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]
```